# Access optimizedTitle field within Twig template

Tags: ajax, plugin-sproutseo, meta

I'm trying to access the value set for my optimized title within Sprout SEO. I've had a read through this page: https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/seo/docs/advanced-customization/custom-metadata-variable - but have had no luck.

Why I want to do this is because I'm loading my pages via AJAX and need to set the title once the content is loaded. I've tried various iterations of `{{ entry.metadata.metadata.optimizedTitle }}` but to no avail.

Alternately, do you know how to set the metadata to update upon each AJAX page load?

Answer (score 1):

So to update this question incase someone happens to stumble across it.

With Sprout SEO you need to enable the `Enable custom metadata variable` option under 'Advanced' in the settings menu.

From there I set a twig variable with the value of my metadata title, in this case `{%- set metaTitle = entry.metadata.title -%}` and attach it to my AJAX wrapper element with something like `data-title="{{ metaTitle }}"`.

Now when I load each page via javascript I just do a little something like this `document.title = $('<div />').append(html).children('.js-ajax-wrapper').data('title');` once the content is loaded in and my page title is updated.